# No connection Ubuntu Server LTS

Tags: networking, server

My VM is on a laptop which have a MediaTek Wi-Fi 6 MT7921 Wireless LAN Card and I don't know why, but there is no connection.

[image]

Comment: You probably need to provide some configuration details. Also, since this i VMWare on Windows, the problem might more be a VMWare/Windows issue than an Ubuntu issue.

Comment: I am using a bridge connection on vmware to have a different ip than the laptop in ubuntu but what info do you need ?

Comment: You've not specified which Ubuntu product you're using, only that it's a LTS.  All *year* products have 10 years of support; but LTS is mentioned only in the *year.month* products (as they have non-LTS products too), but there are multiple currently supported *year.month* products, so which are you using?

Comment: Your screenshot seems to correctly show an emulated connection (eth) for the Guest VM. Try it. That's how VMs work.